# Find occurrences in a List using recursion in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have the an List which can contain just two kind of elements, **Apple** and **Peach**. I need to create a function which, given a list with those elements, returns the number of occurences of **Apple** in the list by using recursion.

Here is my attempt:

```haskell
data Fruit = Apple | Peach
findFruit :: [Fruit] -> Int

findFruit [] = 0

findFruit (y:ys)
    | y==Apple = 1+(findFruit ys)
    | otherwise = findFruit ys
```

But it's not working. I suspect the issue is in the last instructions but I cannot really understand where as I'm still a Haskell newbie.

Here is the error log:

```
Main.hs:7:8:
    No instance for (Eq Fruit) arising from a use of ‘==’
    In the expression: y == Apple
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                   an equation for ‘findFruit’:
      y == Apple
    In an equation for ‘findFruit’:
        findFruit (y : ys)
          | y == Apple = 1 + (findFruit ys)
          | otherwise = findFruit ys
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use pattern matching rather than guards. As in `findFruit (Apple:xs) = ... ; findFruit (Peach:xs) = ...` Adding `deriving Eq` as the answers suggest will also work but pattern matching is idiomatic and preferable.

Comment: By the way - if you call your function `findFruit` I would expect a different type signature, if you're doing this as an exercise try to implement `countFruit :: Fruit -> [Fruit] -> Int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `deriving Eq` to your type constructor. That way, the notion of equality for your type will be automatically implemented and the == operator will be valid for use.

```
data Fruit = Apple | Peach deriving Eq
```

Answer (score 5):

You can leave the data definition as it is and use pattern matching:

```
data Fruit = Apple | Peach

findFruit :: [Fruit] -> Int
findFruit []         = 0
findFruit (Apple:ys) = 1 + findFruit ys
findFruit (Peach:ys) = findFruit ys
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, but he does not know how to compare elements, so, just derive from eq as the compiler is telling you:

```
data Fruit = Apple | Peach deriving (Eq)
```

This way the compiler will have information about this data can be compared.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for modularity and concept reuse with

```
import Data.Monoid

fruit a _ Apple = a    -- case analysis for Fruit 
fruit _ p Peach = p

countFruit = getSum . mconcat . map (fruit (Sum 1) (Sum 0))
```

(though it's not recursive).

Comment: If you want modularity and concept reuse, it's far easier to go for `length . filter (Apple ==)`.

Comment: @gallais not without adding the `Eq` constraint. And not if you want to sum up prices, say, for all fruits, which my code easily and trivially allows for. i.e. *"ease of extension and modification"*. :)

Comment: Why not `countFruit = sum . map (fruit 1 0)` then?

Comment: I just thought of `mconcat` first, and `Sum` was a later detail.